# getting 500 internal server error on rest call

Tags: java, rest, http-status-code-500

getting this error after hibernate outputs the data, any idea why this would be happening. please help!

```
Sep 07, 2016 12:07:00 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bendb]
Sep 07, 2016 12:07:00 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 3 * Server responded with a response on thread http-nio-8080-exec-5
3 < 200
3 < Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
3 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
3 < Allow: OPTIONS
3 < Content-Type: application/json

Sep 07, 2016 12:07:00 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 4 * Server responded with a response on thread http-nio-8080-exec-5
4 < 500
```

Comment: Anytime you get a 500, your FIRST stop should be the webserver's error logs to get details about the 500.

Comment: thanks, i am using eclipse with tomcat. where may i check webserver error logs? I have not changed anything other than writing more code and it failed today where as was working yesterday. so confusing.

Comment: @MarcB sorry forgot to tag..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry found a bug in my code so apparently the code change i made was trying to map all the junction tables (collections) in that get user rest call hence jersey just breaks out while attempting to do that. un Commenting that code and just passing the normal data sets solved the issue.